# Java impose 'state' through interfaces

Tags: java

Can I impose 'state' through interfaces in Java? I am building a simple API that allows clients to register 'data stores', 'datasets' and 'dataelements' (database guys read databases, tables and columns) and for API providers to extend the basic API and implement it for a specific platform. So a MySQL provider will have an implementation, an oracle provider implementation so on.

I was thinking of setting up dataset interface and a dataelement interface with the 'behaviors' I am looking to provide my clients. However, I notice sometimes I need to ensure a particular state of the implementation.

For eg -

when I want to register a 'dataset', I  want to ensure that the 'data store' already 'isConnected';

I also want to ensure a 'dataset' instance is never returned to a caller without having its 'list of dataelements' initialized

Is there a way to impose this on those implementing my interfaces?

Comment: I think you'll need an abstract class for that.  Interfaces can have default methods but I don't think that's going to help with "state."  BTW, check out Apache DbUtils: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/

Comment: Thanks markspace. However I am trying to avoid inheritance - in this case, for the providers of my API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Java 8, you can implement default methods and make them final (I think?) in order to impose restrictions on the set of possible states.

Other alternatives are to use an abstract class or to have a normal class which takes an implementation of the interface as a constructor parameter and stores it as a private variable.

Comment: Should I add a 'provisioning' type that accepts client requests for these objects (datastores/datasets/dataelements) and gives me the opportunity to construct instances of these implementations in a controlled fashion?